# How long is data stored in Live Share's hosted service accessible?

Tags: microsoft-teams, live-share

We are using Microsoft Teams Live Share SDK to build collaborative app. How long is data stored in Live Share's hosted service accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data stored in a Live Share container should be transient in nature. It CAN live for up to 24 hours but is not guaranteed to live past the end of the meeting in which it's created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Any data sent or stored through Fluid containers created by Live Share's hosted Azure Fluid Relay service is accessible for 24 hours. If you want to persist data beyond 24 hours, you can replace our hosted Azure Fluid Relay service with your own. Alternatively, you can use your own storage provider in parallel to Live Share's hosted service.

Documentation: https://aka.ms/teamsliveshare